# Bash foreach line split on space

Tags: bash

I have a plain text file, that is formatted like:

```
10 https://google.com
22 https://facebook.com
```

I'd like to parse this file in a bash script and for each line and the number before the url make that many wget requests to the url.

I know I can simply read in the file with:

```
 URLS=$(cat ./urls)
```

But how do I split on the number and space and newlines and run the wget command for each line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `read` to read each part into a variable, and `while` to loop through the lines.

```
while read prio url
do
   ...
done < ./urls
```

Comment: Though I wouldn't call it `prio` as the number represents a "count" instead of a "priority".